# Sphere in 3D calculus

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of the sphere if one of its diameters has endpoints $(-1, -10, -2)$ and $(2, -4, 7)$. The equation should be normalized so that the coefficient of $x_2$ is $1$.

Comment: Please show us what you've already tried.

Comment: A diameter passes through the center of the sphere. In fact, as each side of the center is a radius of the sphere, the center is the midpoint. And gosh, the length of the diameter is twice the radius. So you know the center, and the you know the radius, and isn't that all you need to write the equation of the sphere?

Answer (score 0):

You've given a diameter. The midpoint of the diameter is the center. The midpoint can be found by averaging each component of the two endpoints.

midpoint: $(0.5, -7, 2.5)$

The radius is the distance from the center to one of the given endpoints. Calculate using the distance formula. I leave this calculation to you.

The equation for a sphere in 3space is given by

$$ r^2 = (x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2$$

where $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is the center of the sphere and $r$ is the radius.

Since this is a sphere, the coefficient in front of each $x,y,z$ must be the same and therefore can be divided out.